# How to reverse word leaving all instance of q in place

Tags: java, string, reverse, cpu-word

How do I write a method that will reverse the letters of each word in a string while leaving all instances of ‘Q’ or ‘q’ in place (stay at the current index).  Each word is separated by whitespace(‘ ‘).

Examples:

```
Hello Worldq > olleH dlroWq
Hiq BQb -> iHq bQB
kjnoqKl -> lKonqjk
jkQuq -> ukQjq
```

---

```
public String reverseWords(String s) {
    String[] sub = s.trim.split(“q + ”);
    String result = ””;
    if (sub.length > 0) {
        for (int i = sub.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            result += sub[i] + ““;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do not be afraid to show us your code. Also if the `Q` stays in place would `queen` be `qneeu`?

Comment: Split the string on spaces, and for each word use a for loop with i = 0; up to i = length of array / 2. Go through each letter only swapping places if the letter is not q

Comment: Example input and output expected please?

Comment: @Perdomoff please help. i have put input and output

Comment: He edited the question, why are you guys still downvoting?

Comment: We still don't know what the specific problem is. Error? Exception? Wrong output? What are we fixing here? All we have right now is an assignment.

Comment: @YassinHajaj because this is still just a homework dump with the OP begging for help

Comment: @gonzo yes the q stays in place

Comment: @redFIVE I can not agree with you. He has already tried something and is stuck.. He does not ask us to do his homework...

Comment: @YassinHajaj you agreeing with me is not required for me answering your question.

Comment: @redFIVE I just wanted to point out that this is not a regular "do my homework" post...

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. What I did first was parse the initial `String` so we can get individual words. From there, I replaced all the `Q` and `q` for that word with an empty string and then reversed it using `StringBuilder`. Well with `StringBuilder` you can also insert pretty easily, so I looped back through the word and added all the `Q` and `q` back to the orginial spot.

```
public static void main(String... array){
    System.out.println(reverseWords("Hello Worldq"));
}

public static String reverseWords(String s) {
    String[] words = s.split(" ");
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(words.length);
    for (String word : words){  //Iterate through words
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(word.replaceAll("[Qq]", "")).reverse(); //Replace Q's and reverse
        for (int i =0; i<word.length(); i++){  //find Q's
            char tempChar = s.charAt(i);
            if (tempChar == 'Q'){  //If q found insert
                temp.insert(i, "Q");
            }
            if (tempChar == 'q'){
                temp.insert(i, "q");
            }
        }
        output.append(temp); //Add to final output
        output.append(" ");  //Do not forget about space
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**
Some after thoughts, you could potentially store the indexes of the Q's when iterating through the word initially when trying to replaceAll. That way you replaceAll and have the indexes of all the Q's with one iteration instead of 2.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in two step. First of all, construct a list, or array containing all letters that are not Q or q. Reverse the array.

Then you reconstruct the array by replacing all the non q letters with the reveresed array like this:

```
int reversedIndex = 0;
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
  if (s.charAt(i) != 'q' && s.charAt(i) != 'Q') {
    s[i] = reversedArray[reversedIndex];
    reversedIndex++;
  }
}
```

I leave you to make the code to program the reversedArray

Answer (score 1):

Why not just implement a spare string/array with the q or Q included, reverse the string/array to the place -1 space for the q or Q, and if you come across one in your word/place in the array just do nothing be an if statement in your reverse method.Then put that in an string/array. Take the next part of the string/array and do the same until your original word is empty, return the final string/array, whatever you want to use, and done